# How to find height and width of point where we want to place our div in #css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created 4 `div` in my html. `Div` contains heading, paragraph and parallax image in background. Now what i want to put my text i.e heading and paragraph in some exact point inside div.

**How to find the dimension of point where i want to place my text inside div.
    Help guys.**

```
 div{

        height: 600px;
        /* background-color: grey; */
        margin:   0px;
        padding: 0px;

    }



    h1{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 90px;  
    }

    p{
    text-align: center;
    }

    .center{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width : auto;
        padding-top: 250px;
    }
```

Comment: you dont position stuff absolutely like that

Answer (score 1):

In this if you can place the header and paragraph in anywhere in the div by using position property like this,

```
.div{
      height: 600px;
      width:100%;
      float:left;
      position:relative;
      background:gray;
    }
    h1{
       position:absolute;
       top:40px;
       right:40px;
      }
      p{
       position:absolute;
       top:50px;
       right:40px;
      }
```

In above case, h1 40px from top and 40px from right in inside the div.you can move the absolute positiond elemet(h1 or any..) anywhere you want by change the values.
make sure h1 and p must inside the div that have position:relative;